# Export interface in c++/CLI to native c++

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I have a unmanaged (i.e. not ref class)class in c++/CLI implementing an interface in c++/CLI. Both are in the same file Wrapper.h
I want to export only the interface and access the method implementation (of the derived class ) in the native c++. 
I looked for this situation in two books Foundations of C++/CLI by Gordon Hogenson and C++/CLI in ACtion By Nishant Shivakumar Sir. Any workaround for this?

**EDIT**
Below is my Interface in c++/CLI (Wrapper.h). The CSharp (c#)project contains the managed interface ICalculateArea and the class Circle implementing it. FYI...the C# project is being built successfully

```
 #ifdef MANAGED_EXPORT
using namespace System;
using namespace CSharp;
#endif
#ifdef MANAGED_EXPORT
#define DLLAPI  __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLLAPI  __declspec(dllimport)
#pragma comment(lib,"PATH.lib")
#endif



interface class IWrapper
{
  double CalculateArea(double value);
};
```

and a ref class implementing this interface is as follows::(Wrapper.cpp)

```
#include"Wrapper.h"
using namespace CSharp;
   ref class UnmanagedCircle:IUnmanagedCalculateArea
 {

 public:
     virtual double CalculateAreaWrapper()
    {
      ICalculateArea^ getArea=dynamic_cast<ICalculateArea^>(gcnew Circle) ;
      return getArea->CalculateArea();
    }
    virtual double GetRadiusWrapper() 
    {
        Circle^ circle=gcnew Circle();
        return circle->Radius;
    }
    virtual void SetRadiusWrapper(double value )
    {
        Circle^ circle=gcnew Circle();
        circle->Radius=value;
    }
 };
```

Now I want to access the CalculateArea method in a different native c++ project?

Comment: please show some code describing what you want to do excatly, your question is not really clear.

Comment: Have you any issue? Because what you describe should be possible.

Comment: Create a native class that wraps the ref class.

Comment: Or simply implement CalculateArea in c++

Comment: @David HefferMan any examples...about how to do that? and where should i make that in Wrapper.h, Wrapper.cpp or in NativeCpluplus.cpp?

Comment: I have my ref class in Wrapper.cpp

Comment: I'm not sure it matters where you put it. Organise it however fits best for you.

Comment: Edited my question again! @David thankyou but can you elaborate on your previous comment through an example.Do check my edit again about what have I done till now. The handles are the managed c# classes and interfaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need the C++/CLI ref class layer. You can write a native class that wraps the managed objects directly. For example:

```
class UnmanagedCircle
{
public:
    static double CalculateAreaWrapper()
    {
        ICalculateArea^ getArea=dynamic_cast<ICalculateArea^>(gcnew Circle);
        return getArea->CalculateArea();
    }

    static double GetRadiusWrapper() 
    {
        Circle^ circle=gcnew Circle();
        return circle->Radius;
    }

    static void SetRadiusWrapper(double value)
    {
        Circle^ circle=gcnew Circle();
        circle->Radius=value;
    }
};
```

Comment: Sir i need to implement the interface's method CalculateArea here sir! So i used virtual keyword in the that method only. Why u made them static? Mind you, I am getting errors now that Circle and ICalculateArea are undeclared identifiers. I included the CSharp project reference.still showing the same errors.

Comment: I made them static because they do not use instance data. If you want to make them virtual instance methods, feel free to do so. The concept is just the same. There does not seem to be any need for a managed wrapper layer. Your native class cannot implement a managed interface.

Comment: @David..Thanks.. Do check the edit ..Still getting the errors. I seriously believe I'm doing some stupid mistake.Can you help?

Comment: I've given you a conceptual answer. I've not compiled any code and have no intention of doing so. My point is that I see no reason why you have a managed wrapper. You need an unmanaged wrapper if you want to expose functionality to native code. Your edit changes nothing in my view.

Comment: I am exposing my C# methods to native C++ through managed wrapper.If i make it unmanaged, it will not recognize the handles..FYI I'm using c++ interop

Comment: Native C++ cannot consume a managed ref class so you need a native class. At which point why do you think you need a C++/CLI managed ref class to wrap the C# class? That's the crux of my answer and I'm not sure you've grasped what I am saying. I think you have just taken my code, tried to compile it, and come back to me when that failed. You are surely not going to use my code as is. What I'm suggesting is a *technique* for you to solve your problem.

Comment: Used an unmanaged wrapper and did it successfully! Thanks @David Sir!.and a big thanks...C++/CLI Babbye!!

Comment: Good! Thanks for letting me know, and I'm pleased you got there!

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar in VS 2015 (export an unmanaged wrapper function from a C++/CLI project to a caller in an unmanaged native C++ project), but nothing I try works. I always ending up with "error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol".